# Subsetting a df by 2, 3 or more conditions in R

Tags: r, subset

I just started programming in R and I´m trying to undestand more and more about this language. Right now I´m having trouble subsetting a DataFrame (DF). The DF looks like:

Gender  Major                      State  County       Age

1  M       Biological Engineering     Texas  Houston      32
2  F       Chemical Engineering       Texas  San Antonio  54
3  F       Biology                    Texas  Dallas       19
4  M       Chemistry                  Texas  San Antonio  64
5  M       Biological Engineering     Texas  Houston      41
6  F       Architecture               Texas  Houston      50
7  M       Biology                    Texas  Dallas       21
8  M       Architecture               Texas  Fort Worth   30
9  M       Chemical Engineering       Texas  Fort Worth   40
10 F       Biological Engineering     Texas  Dallas       25

the picture in the link below its the same DF:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21RYV.png

I need your help in order to know:

1. Subsetting e.g.: how many students are from San antonio and studying Architecture
2. Subsetting e.g.: how many students are studying Biology and are between 20 - 30 years old
3. Subsetting e.g.: how many student are studying Biology, are between 20 - 30 years old and and are Females
4. Subsetting e.g.: how many student are studying biological Engineering, are between 20 - 30 years old,
   are Females and from Houston

I will really appreciate your answers!

Comment: Try `with(DF,sum( County == 'San antonio" & Major == 'Architecture'))`, similarly `with(DF, sum(Major == 'Biology' & Age > 20 & Age < 30))`.  Use the same logic to get the counts

Comment: Thank yo so much Arun!! Works Perfectly, but I would like to know if its possible to have the conditions: San Antonio (County), Architecture (Major), Female (Gender), range of age, but INSTEAD of writting each of County & Major, maybe doing a loop for having as an outcome a Data.Table with each Major, County, adn the others variables